# 'Undefined' when trying to log dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to generate the carousel images. My JSON object looks like this.

```
{
    "src": "../_shared/img/img1.jpg",
    "title": "Image 1",
    "onclick": "get_src()"
}
```

The final generate HTML is this

```
<img onclick="test()" src="../_shared/img/img1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
```

And now using the JQuery I'm trying to alert the src value but it always returns 'Undefined'

```
function test() {
    alert( $(this).attr('src') );
}
```

So how do I deal with the element which has been dynamically added?

Comment: Your `this` doesn't hold the value you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

In order to refer the element, you need to pass the `this` reference to the function as an argument otherwise `this` within the function would refer to `window` object.

```
<img onclick="test(this)" src="../_shared/img/img1.jpg" alt="Image 1">

function test(ele) {
  alert($(ele).attr('src') );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally forgot about this.